# Is there a win32 API to get the ids of all threads currently in running state?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, kernel

I would like to get a list of all threads that are currently in running state on the operation system (globally, not just for the current running process). The thread unique id is enough.

Currently I use `NtQuerySystemInformation()` with following approach (pseudo code) :

```
var processes = NtQuerySystemInformation(NTQUERYSYSTEMPROCESSINFORMATION);
foreach (var process in processes)
{
   foreach (var thread in process.threads)
   {
       if (thread.state == ThreadState.Running)
       {
          //do something
       }
   }
}
```

It works to some extend but there is a major issue : the information returned by `NtQuerySystemInformation` is not atomic. AFAIK it's atomic per process (the process structure is locked before being copied) but not globally (eg: across all processes and threads).

Because of that, I sometimes get a thread count higher than it should be. For example I might occasionally get 7 threads in running state on a 4C/4T CPU (theoretically it's impossible).

**Disclaimer** : `NtQuerySystemInformation()` is a undocumented NT API. I know it's not supposed to be used and subject to changes. That's the best I got so far. It's OK in my case as I only intend to use it once, it's not intended to be for production use.

---

EDIT:
One possible way for a Windows API to implement what is described here would be to loop on the processors list maintained by the OS and get current thread from there (I don't know how the kernel dispatcher is implemented but it would make sense to have a field per CPU that references current thread).

It wouldn't be perfect since current thread field can be updated while looping on the processors list and the thread doing that job will count itself (but that's OK).

Comment: There's CreateToolhelp32Snapshot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot (not sure is really better) PS: NtQuerySystemInformation is (partially) documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation (the day Microsoft removes this, thousands of program fail...)

Comment: A full example program of what @SimonMourier is referring to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/traversing-the-thread-list

Comment: Thanks. I already took a look at CreateToolhelp32Snapshot. The main issue is that it only returns ProcessID and ThreadID. See [THREADENTRY32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-threadentry32). There is no way to filter on the status.

Comment: `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemProcessInformation` or `SystemExtendedProcessInformation`.  *subject to changes* - nonsense and lie. the `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` one of the worst shells. it takes several times longer and loses information

Comment: *NtQuerySystemInformation is not atomic* - no one method will be atomic here

Comment: That doesn't sound like a meaningful question. The list you're asking for will be stale by the time you're looking at it.

Comment: @IInspectable : that's OK for what I intend to do. Those processes / threads I want to check are long running ones (they stay alive for almost 24H).

Comment: What do you mean by 'in running state'?

Comment: @PaulSanders : see [Thread States](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233328&seqNum=7) section.  In [SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation#system_thread_information) structure, this occurs when `ThreadState == 2`

Comment: If you care about that level of detail, you've got a Heisenburg problem.  The mere fact that your code is counting the number of threads means that it's taking up one of the CPU cores -- you can never get a count of zero.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, the usage of `NtQuerySystemInformation` is not simple like this. It needs to go deep into PEB/TEB. You can see my code, it obtains the target process PEB and obtain various process information.https://gist.github.com/Torrecto/e9486a79ba448a9cb29632ccfcddbd98
If you want to get threads' state in your way, you need to use WinDbg probably.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT if we need only all threads in system with state, we not need go deep into PEB/TEB